# Word counter in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm working on a lab assignment for a web applications class and am stuck on implementing a word counter for a basic HTML webpage. The setup of the tests and HTML are already done for us. I simply need to write a function called countWords that takes a string and returns the number of words. It works differently from your traditional word counter though. A word is defined as anything A-Z. Everything else is considered not part of a word. So, if the string is just `"234@#$^"` then the word count is 0. So, I'm not just counting white space like most word counters. All the answers I've found on StackOverflow to similar questions try to just count white space and don't work for my situation. Hence why I made a new question.

My idea was to have a return statement that matches any grouping of a-z using a regular expression and return the length. Then, have a conditional to check for the empty string or string with no letters a-z.

```
function countWords(s) {
   if(s === "" || s === "%$#^23#") {
      return 0
   }
   return s.match(/[^a-z]/gi).length
}
```

Right now the if statement is just matching the two test cases so that I can pass my tests. I'm not sure how to go about writing another match regular expression to check for no letters in the string or the empty string. Any help is appreciated! Been stuck for a while.

Comment: Surely just `s.match(/[a-z]+/gi).length` is all you need?

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is that it doesn't seem to pass my tests for when the string is ```""``` or ```"%$#^23#"```. It should be returning 0 in those cases, and it isn't.

Comment: What about words containing umlauts etc...? Your *lab* does not considers those as part of valid words/names?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan as far as I understand it, the professor is considering anything with A-Z letters and not broken by whitespace to be a word. I'm going to guess he's not including umlauts and the sort. It's just a basic lab to get us working with regular expressions. It's not meant to be a functioning website or anything.

Comment: @PatrickConboy I guessed right than and I'm angry on such professors. They teach students on a w3schools level, instead of teaching them right. Regexing by the above requirement is absolutely legit, but should be explicitly thought as a regex parser for strict property-names where special characters are forbidden anyways, not as a "Look, here's how you can parse textcontent, *words*!"...

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2953245)

Answer (score 1):

```
const str1 = '%$#^23#';
const str2 = 'String with  ___ special characters and @$&# white spaces  !!!';
const str3 = 'Special &$%# characters --> and %$#^5# connected,words but our <++@@||++> function,still_works!';

const wordCount = (str) => str.replace(/[\W_\d]/g,' ').split(' ').filter(Boolean).length;

console.log(wordCount(str1)); // 0
console.log(wordCount(str2)); // 7
console.log(wordCount(str3)); // 11
```

1. use "regex" to replace all special characters, underscores, numbers, and extra white spaces with an empty space

   --> replace(/[\W_\d]/g,' ')
2. convert the string into an array

   --> .split(' ')
3. use filter to remove all empty string(s) in the array

   --> .filter(Boolean)
4. then, get the word count with "length"

   --> .length

Answer (score 0):

You first need to filter the `string`, remove all the special characters and numbers:

```
var filtered_test = my_text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, '');
```

then do a normal `split` and count:

```
var words = filtered_test.split(" ");
console.log(words.length); //prints out the count of words
```

Comment: It will pass `"Hello&$&$&"`, which OP does not want

Comment: Ramy... `let's` is how many words than? Not to talk about names, words containing a myriad of utf8 characters...

Comment: No, ```"Hello&$&$&"``` would be counted as one word in this case, right? That would match the functionality I need.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it will be counted as 1 word applying the above regex, since " ' " will be filtered out.

Comment: @smac89 `"Hello&&$$&"` would be down sized to `"Hello"`

Comment: The problem with my solution is the multiple spaces which can be solved easily

Answer (score 0):

How about this regular expression: `/.*?[a-z]+.*?(\s|$)/gi`

Use `return s.match(/.*?[a-z]+.*?(\s|$)/gi).length`

Anything with at least 1 letter in it is counted. Then the phrase `O##ne two $#!+ @#%Three four^&&$ five` would count as 5 words.

**Edit**: If you want to be evil to pass your test cases when there are 0 matches use `(input.match(/.*?[a-z]+.*?(\s|$)/gi) || "").length`

Comment: Frustratingly, that does count the words correctly as intended, but it isn't passing the tests for some reason. Very odd. I might see if I can tweak it so it passes the tests that are written.

Comment: Edited answer to include null coalescing operator so null error isn't thrown for your test cases

Answer (score 0):

You can use a functional replace method to chunk all of the "words" into an array, then simply return the array length. This has the added benefit of providing a `0` count:

---

explanatory version:

```
function countWords(str, words = []) {
  str.replace(/[A-Z]+/gi, (m) => words.push(m));
  return words.length;
}
```

---

minimal version:

```
let countWords = (str, words = []) => 
    ( str.replace(/[A-Z]+/gi, (m) => words.push(m)), words.length );
```

```js
let countWords = (str, words = []) => (str.replace(/[A-Z]+/gi, (m) => words.push(m)), words.length);

console.log( "##asdfadf###asfadf: " + countWords("##asdfadf###asfadf") )
console.log("##13424#$#$#$%: " + countWords("##13424#$#$#$%"));
```